# Number of entries and size of the storage

Tags: cognito-forms, online-storage

I am looking for a form making website that can provide me a form capable to store up to 500 entries each having a file of 1 Mb attached to it.

As Cognito has no way to be paid, I'm looking to know if it can provide the space or not. We are obviously talking of something like 600Mb of storage for the time of the conference.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) currently offers unlimited forms, fields, entries and storage.  As we [stated from the beginning](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/whats-cognito-forms-our-online-forms-engine-going-to-cost), we plan to eventually enforce a limit of 500 entries per month and 100MB of storage on our free plan.

We are releasing our paid plans and multi-user support for larger organizations this month.  When we do, we will gradually begin enforcing both the entry and storage limits.  You can find our pricing on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/URksRdbH), including feedback from our customers.

For your specific needs, our $10 Pro plan includes 1GB of storage and 2000 entries per month, so would be your best bet.  For now though, everything is free except payment forms, where we charge just 1% of transactions.